# SWIG typemap for python list to double *

Tags: c++, python, c, swig

How to convert python list using typemap in swig. 
For example :

```
lst = [1.0,2.0,3.3] (Python list)
```

to pass to

```
void print_arg(double *lst){} (c/c++ function)
```

How can I write swig interface file for this.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660270/swig-typemap-for-python-input-and-output-arrays

Comment: @karthikT Thanks for the refernce link

Comment: How would `print_arg` know how many values are in the list?  Use `print_arg(const std::vector<double>& lst)` instead and declare the interface like I suggested in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13401041/235698).

Answer (score 0):

A method to do this is using SWIG and carrays and cpointer

A sample code is :

SWIG interface

```
%include "carrays.i"
%array_class(double, doubleArray);
```

Python module

```
LEVEL = 3
thre = [1, 100, 10000]
a = example.doubleArray(LEVEL)
for i in xrange(LEVEL):
    a[i] = thre[i]

gd=example.GradedDouble(LEVEL,a)
```

The above is working example for me... alter the code accordingly for your purpose...